# bash: stop subshell script marked as failed if one step exits with an error

Tags: bash, unix, slurm

I am running a script through the SLURM job scheduler on HPC.

I am invoking a subshell script through a master script.

The subshell script contains several steps. One step in the script sometimes fails because of the quality of the data; this step is not required for further steps, but if this step fails, my whole subshell script is marked with "failed" Status in the job scheduler.  However, I need this subshell script to have a "completed" Status in the Job scheduler as it is dependency in my master script.

I tried setting up

```
set +e
```

in my subshell script right before the optional step, but it doesn't seem to work: I still get an exitCode with errors and FAILED status inthe job scheduler.

In short: I need the subshell script to have Status "completed" in the job scheduler, no matter whether one particular step is finished with errors or not. Will appreciate help with this.

Comment: You seem to mentions some strange `to be marked as "completed"` or `marked as "failed"` or some `step is finished` which look like they are referring to some particular toolchain or library. What is a "mark" and what, how and why is "marking" anything? What are "steps"? `I am invoking a subshell script through a master script.` Does your "master script" "mark" the subshell? What are the rules that make decision to which "mark" does the subshell belong? Please post an [MCVE] and please post the content of the "master script".

Comment: I am running the script on HPC (slurm job scheduler); what I am referring to as "Marked Failed" is State "Failed" (I need COMPLETED as opposed to FAILED) and ExitCode (I need 0:0).

Comment: [tag:slurm] added.

Comment: It sounds like you need to rewrite the subscript so that it does not fail when the optional step fails.

Comment: It would help if you expounded on "doesn't seem to work".  Details are helpful.

Comment: I edited my initial post. I would like to avoid to rewrite the script because it is run on the  HPC using  arrays, and submitting a whole new array of jobs with relatively small steps is not encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Slurm jobs submitted with `sbatch`, the job exit code is taken to be the return code of the submission script itself. The return code of a Bash script is that of the last command in the script.

So if you just end your script with `exit 0`, Slurm should consider it `COMPLETED` no matter what.